# Search filtration in Angularjs with Array Value

Tags: arrays, angularjs, filter

I will have an array when the user multi choose 'Author' from peoplepicker.when they choose a people,I want to filter the array with the corresponding DisplayText using `ng-repeat="item in filteredart =(filteredArticles |filter: AuthorArray ")`

So Now I can filter the array with a single value like `$scope.AuthorArray="sridhar"`.but I cant filter with multiple values `$scope.AuthorArray="sridhar,Alan"`.

Help me, I'm new :)

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to filter.  What does the array of values you are trying to filter look like?  Please provide more code/context for your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I have used other method which I know.But instead of using filter on `ng-repeat` I used a button to trigger the filter. Thanks :)

`

```
 $scope.authorChange = function () {
            var ppick = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict.peoplePickerDiv_TopSpan;
            var filteredArticlestemp = [];
            $scope.authorarray= getUsers(ppick);
            //$scope.authorarray = $scope.authorarray.join();
            for (var j = 0; j < $scope.authorarray.length; j++) {
                for (var i = 0; i < $scope.filteredArticles.length; i++) {
                    if ($scope.filteredArticles[i].Author == $scope.authorarray[j]) {
                        filteredArticlestemp.push($scope.filteredArticles[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
            $scope.filteredArticles = filteredArticlestemp;
        }
        function getUsers(peoplePicker) {

            // Get information about all users.
            var users = peoplePicker.GetAllUserInfo();
            var userInfo = [];
            if (users.length > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
                    var user = users[i];
                    userInfo.push(user.DisplayText);

                }
            }


            return userInfo;
        }
```

`

```
`<div id="peoplePickerDiv" ng-model="authorsearch"></div>
 <input type="button" value="Refine" ng-click="authorChange()" />`
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not clearly getting your question but as far as I understood it, I think what you need is to write a custom filter.

In this example, **matchMyCriteria** matches all items in the array with the list of available names in **AuthorArray** array.

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | filter: matchMyCriteria()">
{{ item }}
</div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.items = [{title: "abc", author: "Alan", .....}, ......];
$scope.AuthorArray = ["sridhar", "Alan"];
$scope.matchMyCriteria = function() {
  return function(item) {
    return ($scope.AuthorArray.indexOf(item.author) > -1);
  };
};
```

There is another solution for it and I assume it to be the good one.

In this example, **myFilter** is used to filter the array of items on the basis of an array of authors.

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | myFilter: AuthorArray">
    {{item}}
</div>
```

JS:

```
app.filter('myFilter', function() {
  return function(list, criteria) {
    return list.filter(function(l) {
      return (criteria.indexOf(l.author) > -1);
    });
  };
});
```